# Changing Xamarin Label in ListCell does not work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with a ListView. I want each Cell to have a label and a switch but the text of the label does not appear.

Here is my code:

```
public class FilterPage : ContentPage
{
    public FilterPage()
    {
        List<FilterCell> listContent = new List<FilterCell>();
        foreach(string type in Database.RestaurantTypes)
        {
            FilterCell fc = new FilterCell();
            fc.Text = type;

            listContent.Add(fc);
        }
        ListView types = new ListView();
        types.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(FilterCell));
        types.ItemsSource = listContent;

        var layout = new StackLayout();
        layout.Children.Add(types);

        Content = layout;
    }
}

public class FilterCell : ViewCell
{
    private Label label;
    public Switch CellSwitch { get; private set; }
    public String Text{ get { return label.Text; } set { label.Text = value; } }


    public FilterCell()
    {
        label = new Label();
        CellSwitch = new Switch();

        var layout = new StackLayout
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = { label, CellSwitch }
        };
        View = layout;
    }
}
```

If I enter a fixed Text in the FilterCell-Constructor it works fine (e.g.: label.Text = "Hello World")

When I create a Method for the ItemSelected-Event and read out the SelectedItem.Text Property I get the text I assigned as Value but it's never displayed. Only the switch is displayed when I try to run this Code.

Thanks for your help
Niko

Comment: @Jason the code I posted does not work for me. It does not produce an error but I can't see the label text

Just Replace Database.RestaurantTypes with any List of Strings

Comment: I just assigned the label the Text "Just a Test" in the constructor and this is what is displayed in the app
But when I check the label.Text in debugging mode it's not that what is displayed :(

Is there a possibility to update the layout? I didn't find one :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh boy. This code looks like a rape (sorry I had to say this).

Now let's see what's wrong:

The reason is you are mixing up data and view **heavily**.

The line

```
types.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(FilterCell));
```

means: "For each item in the list (`ItemsSource`) create **a new** filter cell". The `FilterCell`s that you create in the loop are never displayed.

**The easy fix**

```
public class FilterPage : ContentPage
{
    public FilterPage()
    {
        var restaurantTypes = new[] {"Pizza", "China", "German"}; // Database.RestaurantTypes
        ListView types = new ListView();
        types.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var cell = new SwitchCell();
            cell.SetBinding(SwitchCell.TextProperty, ".");
            return cell;
        });
        types.ItemsSource = restaurantTypes;
        Content = types;

    }
}
```

- There is a standard cell type that contains a label and a switch `SwitchCell`, use it.
- As `ItemsSource` of your list, you have to use your **data**. In your case the list of restaurant types. I just mocked them with a static list.
- The DataTemplate creates the `SwitchCell` and sets the Databinding for the Text property. This is the magic glue between View and data. The "." binds it to the data item itself. We use it, because our list contains items of strings and the Text should be exactly the string. (read about Databinding: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Data_Binding )
- I striped away the `StackLayout` that contained the list. You can directly set the list as `Content` of the page.

**Lesson**

- use standard controls, if possible
- You should always try to remember to keep data and view apart from each other and use data binding to connect to each other.
- Try to avoid unnecessary views.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my code - looking now over it it looks really like rape.
Meanwhile I found out about the SwitchCell myself, still I couldn't link it to the data, so your solution is very helpfull, thank you!

I have a **follow up question**: Because I need the results I thought about creating a struct containing a `string Name` and a `bool Enabled`.
No I have trouble to bind those Properties to the SwitchCell. As ItemSource I passed a List of those Structs.

Comment: `cell.SetBinding(SwitchCell.TextProperty, "Name")` and `cell.SetBinding(SwitchCell.IsEnabledProperty, "Enabled");`

Comment: Hi, I had and have exactelly this code but it doesn't work.

I can't find what I'm doing wrong:
I will ask in a new question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030732/cant-set-binding-of-switchcell-in-xamarin)