# Can't set Binding of SwitchCell in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a SwitchCell with a list of Elements.
Eventhough I found out how to do that with a plain string-List thanks to stackoverflow I can't find out what I'm doing wrong when I try to bind the Cell-Properties to a self-made struct.

This is my code:

```
public class RestaurantFilter
{
    public List<FilterElement> Types;

    public RestaurantFilter(List<string> types)
    {
        Types = new List<FilterElement>();

        foreach (string type in types)
            Types.Add(new FilterElement { Name = type, Enabled = false });
    }
}

public struct FilterElement
{
    public string Name;
    public bool Enabled;
}

public FilterPage()
{
    List<string> l = new List<string>(new string[] { "greek", "italian", "bavarian" });
    RestaurantFilter filter = new RestaurantFilter(l);

    ListView types = new ListView();
    types.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        var cell = new SwitchCell();
        cell.SetBinding(SwitchCell.TextProperty, "Name");
        cell.SetBinding(SwitchCell.IsEnabledProperty, "Enabled");
        return cell;
    });
    types.ItemsSource = filter.Types;

    Content = types;

}
```

But the SwitchCell's in the Application do not show the Name or the Boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the IsEnabledProperty - there seem to be a knonw bug with the IsEnabled property that will be fixed in the Xamarin.Forms 2.3.0-pre1 release so that might be related to your case:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25662

About the Name property - try changing your FilterElement struct to a class with properties and PropertyChangedEventHandler like this and it will work:

```
public class FilterElement
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _enabled;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return _enabled; }
        set
        {
            _enabled = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Enabled"));
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

That way you will be able to update the Types list and it will automatically update the ListView.

By the way, if you want to turn the filter on or off based on your ViewModels (not enable or disable it), you need to use the OnProperty for the binding:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Xamarin.Forms.SwitchCell.OnProperty/

Comment: Thanks for also pointing out that I use the wrong Property! :)